# How to select specific web elements in a tab whose "nth-of-type" location within the website changes after every request?

Tags: html, xpath, web-scraping, css-selectors

I am scraping data from a webservice that organizes its output in several tabs. Every tab is identically structured but has a specific data-id and specific text content.

**Tab with data of interest:**

```
<li class="tab" data-id="CHINA">
```

The challenge is that when I enter different parameters to the webservice, the order and number of tabs in the output can change.

Therefore, the classic `nth-of-type(n)` CSS selector approach won't work, because my `.target_value` may be at a different `nth-of-type` location each time.

**This will only work if my data are in tab 2, otherwise it returns the wrong data:**

```
li:nth-of-type(2) > div.long > div.selector > div.to > .target_value
```

**What I need is something like this:**

```
li:nth-of-type(data-ID="CHINA") > div.long > div.selector > div.to > .target_value
```

**How to select specific web elements in a tab whose "nth-of-type" location within the website changes after every request?**

---

CSS is not a requirement, XPath is also fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also [select elements based on attributes and their values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors). Your last suggestion came pretty close:

```
li[data-id="CHINA"] > div.long > div.selector > div.to > .target_value
```

this should work as long as the respective property is set.

Answer (score 1):

No need of **`nth-of-type(n)`** here.

You can select element by using attributes.

```css
li[data-id="CHINA"] {
 color: red;
}
li[data-id="JAPAN"] {
 color: orange;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="tab" data-id="CHINA">
      <div class="target_value">target_value </div>
    </li>
    <li class="tab" data-id="JAPAN">
      <div class="target_value">target_value </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: thanks, I saw that - the thing is that I already have the CSS selectors for the tab content, and am not sure if there are additional selectable  attributes (like color in your example) in my target